# While running a Pig job, showing delay after Snappy native library gets loaded

Tags: hadoop

In the log below, you will see that after Snappy native library loaded, it took around 20 mins to proceed.

Can anyone tell me the issue and the resolution?
Is it due to some network issue?

```
2013-04-09 06:29:42,639 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=MAP, sessionId=
2013-04-09 06:29:43,947 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 1024
2013-04-09 06:29:44,434 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 816043776/1020054736
2013-04-09 06:29:44,435 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 2684354/3355443
2013-04-09 06:29:44,448 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
2013-04-09 06:29:44,448 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
2013-04-09 06:48:29,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output: record full = true
2013-04-09 06:48:29,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 423372603; bufvoid = 1020054736
2013-04-09 06:48:29,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 0; kvend = 2684354; length = 3355443
2013-04-09 06:49:32,969 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor
```